# Value undefined does not allow function calls

Tags: air

I am using aptana + adobe Air 2.0, i have created a page..
while executing the page, its giving the following error..

***TypeError: Value undefined does not allow function calls.***

I have tried to copy a small content into the clip board.. code is below

```
holdtext.innerText = getID.id;
Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
```

holdtext is an id of a text area - from that i just try to copy a small content into the clipboard..
Could you please tell me wat's the problem and how to get ride of this problem

Thanks

Praveen J

Comment: You most definitely need to include more information, specifically what the classes are for "holdText" and "Copied".

Comment: holdtext is an id of a text area - from that i just try to copy a small content into the clipboard..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var holdtext = document.getElementById("holdtext");
```

then:

```
holdtext.innetText = getID.id;
```